# Windows incorrectly copying files by filename when in a Special Folder

Tags: windows, windows-7, desktop, relative-path

If I copy a file from a [special folder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder) to the clipboard, change the location that special folder points to, and try to paste the file to this new location, Windows complains with a `Item Not Found error`, seemingly trying to copy the file by the filename alone.

The way I change the special folder location is with this line of C++ code:

```
SHSetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Desktop, 0, NULL, new_location);
```

And a refresh to see the effect immediately:

```
SHChangeNotify(0x8000000, 0x1000, NULL, NULL);
```

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Desktop pointing to `C:\Users\BoppreH\Desktop`
2. Copy the file `music 1.mp3` from the Desktop (`C:\Users\BoppreH\Desktop\music 1.mp3`)
3. Change location of the Desktop special folder to `D:\music`
4. The Desktop now shows the musics from `D:\music`
5. Try to paste `music 1.mp3` on the Desktop

It fails with `Item Not Found`, complaining it could not find the file at `D:\music\music 1.mp3`, when the file is still happily sitting at `C:\Users\BoppreH\Desktop\music 1.mp3`. If I paste the file in any other folder that is not the Desktop, it works fine.

I know this is a case of *Doctor, it hurts when I do this*, and that constantly changing the location of the Desktop is extremely unusual behavior, but this is a feature I've grown to love and this bug constantly bites me.

Is there some workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some type of `folder watcher` control to detect when the Special Folders location has changed and check the clipboard for any file paths that refer to the old location and update them.

Or change the location of the Specials before you copy the file.

Comment: Great idea, but using `GetClipboardData`, the only clipboard format available is `CF_HDROP` and it returns a list of all copied files *already in their correct absolute paths*. Yet when I try to paste, Windows still complains it couldn't find the file in the new folder. I'm not sure if I can apply the second workaround, but I'll think about that.

Comment: My mistake, there were other formats, but `CF_HDROP` alone was enough to copy the files. Before changing the Desktop I copy the data in `CF_HDROP`, empty the clipboard, and put only `CF_HDROP` back again. Now Windows only has access to the absolute paths and successfully copy the files. No side effects so far. Thank you very much.